# Moving users from one Ec2 machine to another

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

I have an Amazon Linux machine, where users log in and connect to other servers (Bastion server), now I have upgraded my Linux machine to.

How do I move all the users present in server1 to Server2

Things I have tried:

1. created snapshots of Server1
2. converted to volumes and attached it to Server2.

Please suggest what else I can do to get all users from Server1

Comment: Please explain in detail what's wrong with "Things I have tried"? What exactly did you do and why it does not work.

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for [sf]

Comment: i have added the volumes to the new AL2 instance and i dont see users in /etc/passwd and also /home locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **not** create snapshots of the boot disk, since it contains the Operating System.

Instead, you should:

- Start with the raw **Amazon Linux 2 image**
- **Create the new users** in the Operating System. See: [Add new user accounts with SSH access to an EC2 Linux instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/)
- Copy the `/usr/USERNAME` directories **from the old instance to the new instance**

This will preserve the users' settings and SSH keys.

Comment: thanks, John will try this and get back...

Comment: What if i have 200 users in AL1, i need to create all again ?

Comment: Might help: [How to move or migrate user accounts from old Linux server to a new Linux server](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-move-migrate-user-accounts-old-to-new-server/)

Answer (score 0):

copied all the main files, passwd, group, and shadow files from etc and rebooted it worked.